# How can I output javascript with "onclick" into a textfield?

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

I wrote a javascript program to generate random passwords. How can I output the result into a textfield (input tag)?

```js
var randomString = function(length) {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "!@[|^]µ§$%&?*€#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz1234567890";
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

var rs = randomString(16);
console.log(rs);
```

```html
<section id="passgen">
  <button type="button" id="pass-button" onclick="**???**">Generate Password</button>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="output">
</section>
```

Comment: W3Schools has great tutorial on how to write onclick functions or manipulate DOM elements...

Comment: set id for input tag, using javascript access the input filed and set the value

Comment: I think for a beginner it's better if you watch video tutorials about javascript manipulate DOM element(s)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good idea to add an inline click event, you can use `addEventListener` instead.

So here, I am first selecting the element using `document.getElementById` and attaching a `click` event for the same, and later, using `document.getElementsByName()` I select the output element and print the randomized string.

Also note the `[0]` which am using with `document.getElementsByName()` is because if the code encounters multiple elements with the name of `output`, we select the first one, as it returns an array of matched elements. It will be great if you can add some `id` to the `input` field and then use `document.getElementById()` to select a specific element.

```js
var randomString = function(length) {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "!@[|^]µ§$%&?*€#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz1234567890";
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

document.getElementById('pass-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByName('output')[0].value = randomString(16);
});
```

```html
<section id="passgen">
  <button type="button" id="pass-button">Generate Password</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="output">
</section>
```

Comment: Great explanation !! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
var randomString = function(length) {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "!@[|^]µ§$%&?*€#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz1234567890";
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));   
        }
        return text;
    }

    var rs = randomString(16);

    console.log(rs);

    document.getElementsByName('output')[0].value = rs;
```

Comment: jQuery for this, really?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple `document.getElementById("id_of_input_field").value = rs;`
or else you can use name of input box to target `document.getElementsByName('output')[0].value = rs;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var randomString = function(length) {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "!@[|^]µ§$%&?*€#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz1234567890";
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));   
        }
        return text;
    }

var generatePassword = function(length) {
document.getElementById('password').value = randomString(length);
}
```

```html
<section id="passgen">
<button type="button" id="pass-button" onclick="generatePassword(16)">Generate Password</button>
<br><br>
<input id='password' type="text" name="output">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your input an ID, then:

```
document.getElementById('yourInputID').value = rs;
```